# Помогите расставить последовательно темы( Java)

Tags: веб-программирование

Дали много тем по Java:

1. Web service
2. Framevork spring
3. Http протокол
4. Rabitmq
5. Xml/json
6. Orm fremwork (hibernate)
7. Mysql
8. Postgrese
9. Apache
10. Ubunto
11. Soap, rest
12. Web socket
13. Kafka
14. Службы
15. Posgrese/mssql/mysql/tarantul/mongodb

Можете пожалуйста расставить последовательно, что учить первым, а что последним?

Answer (score -1):

Тут конечно список не маленьний, но если чисто Back идет, то начинать с:

1. HTTP
2. REST API
3. XML/JSON ( в целом это будет к REST, обмен в этом формате идет)
4. SOAP ( хотя HTTP куда более прогрессивно )
5. SQL и подобное + ORM SQL
6. NoSQL ( mongo)
7. Ubuntu... (смотря что тут нужно)...

Comment: Без пояснений, почему очередность должна быть именно такой, толку от ответа маловато ..

Comment: Ты там пару тем пропустил: Spring, Hibernet,Rabitmq,Postgrese,Apache,Web socket и Kafka

Comment: Да это все равно смерть... Такой объем ... Нужно много терпения, времени, практики и так далее ...

Comment: Та мне так базу знать хотя бы, для чего это служит, основы короче)

Comment: @Kromster могли бы свой вариант написать, с пояснениями ...

Comment: @ДенисМельников если мог бы - написал бы (или дополнил ваш).